# One magento web site for two hostings

Tags: magento-1.9

We have a website created on magento cms. It is on server located in Russia. Now we want this site to work in China. But our chinese partners say that their internet is slow and our site will be very slow. That's why they want our site to work also on their hosting (in China) but at the same time it has to be synchronized with our site (catalog, customers,orders). Is this a good idea? Or maybe there is a the best decision of this?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably best off using a VPS in Hong Kong or somewhere near China. The latency these days with a server on the other side of the world is pretty low.

My suggestion would be just to test it and run it from one server.